# How can i avoid the inner loop

Tags: java, java-stream

How can i avoid the inner loop and write this 'allocation' only with stream features?
*Edit:* I want a list of all unique pairs catenated together, stored in `l2`.
Example: Input: `String[] l = { "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d" };`, output: `[a, a, b, c, d, d, b, b, c, d]`.

```java
String[] l = { "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "a", "a" };
String[] l2 = 
        IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < l.length, i -> i + 2)
        .mapToObj(i -> Objects.hash(l[i], l[i + 1]))
        .distinct()
        .map(h -> {
            for (int j = 0; j < l.length; j += 2) {
                if (h == Objects.hash(l[j], l[j + 1])) {
                    return new String[] { l[j], l[j + 1] };
                }
            }
            return null;
        })
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(l2));
```

Comment: Hi @unknown_dcba. Can you please add more explanation to your question and tell us what problem are you trying to solve? We can't tell reading from your code why do you even need an inner loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not completely sure of what your loop is trying to achieve. Jason's loop finds all unique characters, but it looks like you're looking for all unique string pairs, then flattened. Your use of "Objects.hash()" to eliminate duplicate pairs is incorrect, it is possible for two pairs to be different but have the same hash, so Jason is right to get rid of that. If you really want a list of unique pairs catenated together, this would probably work:

```
IntStream.range(0, l.length / 2)
  .mapToObj(i -> List.of(l[i * 2], l[i * 2 + 1]))
  .distinct()
  .flatMap(List::stream)
  .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Many thanks! This works fine. /e I've to write `IntStream.range(0,l.length / 2)`.

Comment: Yeah I forgot the "0," in the range. Sorry, I didn't have time to test my code, but I'm glad you were able to fix it. And now that Holger was able to fix it here it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any of that. You can literally use distinct() on the stream to get all distinct values.

```java
String[] distinct = Stream.of(l).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
```